# Remote image on NavigationButton in Nativescript/Angular

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to put the user's avatar on the left of my app's header. It works fine in IOS, but it doesn't work in android. I tried to do this:

```
    <NavigationButton [icon]="customImage" color="#a81b38" (tap)="toggleSideDrawer()" *ngIf="isAndroid">
        <StackLayout verticalAlignment="center">
            <Label id="avatarImg" height="45" width="45" borderRadius="50" backgroundColor="#eeeeee"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationButton>
```

but I get an error during compilation. The custom image is a remote image (https://myimage), but android is looking into local file resources.

So I removed the icon and I put the image inside, trying this:

```
 <NavigationButton color="#a81b38" (tap)="toggleSideDrawer()" *ngIf="isAndroid">
    <StackLayout verticalAlignment="center">
        <Label [style.background-image]="customImage" style.background-position="center"
            style.background-size="cover" class="avatarImage" height="30" width="30" borderRadius="50"
            backgroundColor="#eeeeee"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
</NavigationButton>
```

I don't get any error, but I can't see anything in my header, it's all white. I tried also to use  instead of , but same issue

Comment: Remote image is not supported, try downloading the image and assign the local file url. If you want to use `background-image`, you must follow the CSS syntax `url(imageurl)`. Also background image works based on available space, when your label doesn't have any text, the size of the label will be zero, try setting a fixed width & height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the `<NavigationButton>` for android and putting the `<StackLayout>` directly inside your `<ActionBar>` with a `horizontalAlignment` set to 'left'

```html
<ActionBar>
  <StackLayout *ngIf="isAndroid" horizontalAlignment="left" verticalAlignment="center">
    <Label [style.background-image]="customImage" style.background-position="center"
            style.background-size="cover" class="avatarImage" height="30" width="30" borderRadius="50"
            backgroundColor="#eeeeee"></Label>
  </StackLayout>
</ActionBar>
```